# Docker with Kibana and elasticsearch ! Do I need logstash?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to configure docker-compose with kibana and elasticsearch and I would like to know do I need logstash as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you don't need the Logstash functionality, you don't need it.

Simple example with Elasticsearch and Kibana would be:

```
---
version: '2'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:$ELASTIC_VERSION
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:$ELASTIC_VERSION
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

Kibana credentials (if you are using version 5):

```
login: elastic
password: changeme
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? You need to have a *.env* file in the same directory, which specifies the version — for example: `ELASTIC_VERSION=6.0.1`

Comment: the problem is missing vm.max_map_count=262144 which breaks elasticsearch start.

Comment: Ah, that might be required if you run `docker-machine` for Windows as opposed to Docker for Window (or in production mode, but the Docker Compose file above doesn't use production mode).

Comment: In windows additionally you need to login into "docker-machine ssh default" and execute "sysctl -w  vm.max_map_count=262144"